# How to get the Reset Password mac OS notification to disappear

Tags: password, notifications

I recently reset my Apple ID the other day, and ever since my Mac always prompts me with a notification to reset my password from my device. It was annoying me so I eventually re-reset my password just to get it to go away, but it's still showing up.

Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: What do you see when you select "Show"?

Answer (score 2):

I would try to disconnect and reconnect the Mac from your iCloud account and such services, to see if that stops the notification from showing up.